# Vertical alignment of pgfgantt calendar

Tags: vertical-alignment, pgfgantt, strut

The `pgfgantt` package is generally pretty good about vertically aligning labels, but its `\gantttitlecalendar[`*options*`]{`*calendar lines*`}` command doesn't seem to do this automatically.  This is easily seen when producing a calendar of old-style numbers, which fail to align at the baseline:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage[osf]{mathpazo}
\begin{document}
\begin{ganttchart}{1}{10}
\gantttitlecalendar{day}
\end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

[image: pgfgantt chart showing misaligned calendar]

I assume that this can be fixed by adding a `\strut` before each calendar entry, but it's not clear to me how to do this. (Is there a generic way that will work regardless of the value of the *calendar lines* parameter?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just abuse `title label font` to insert the `\strut`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage[osf]{mathpazo}
\begin{document}
\begin{ganttchart}[%
    title label font=\strut
]{1}{10}
\gantttitlecalendar{day}
\end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks; that seems to work!  I wonder why the package doesn't do something like this automatically (since it _does_ automatically apply a `\strut` to bar and group labels).  Maybe I'll report this to the package maintainer.